# Kehren und fegen

Tags: usage, verb, synonym

I'm currently learning the verb Kehren with the meaning to sweep. But I recently realized that I've already learnt fegen as meaning to sweep. Is this correct, are fegen and kehren totally interchangeable synonyms? Or does one have a slightly different meaning to the other?

I'd love some examples too.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

These words mean the same thing ("to sweep", "to clean dryly with a broom"), but are used in different regions. *Kehren* (or variants thereof, such as *zusammenkehren*) can mostly be heard in southern Germany and Austria, whereas *fegen* is commonly used in the North.

Oddly  enough, the Swiss say *wischen* for "to sweep", which a German would (mis-)understand as "to mop" (*feucht wischen*) or "to dust" (*Staub wischen*)..

The *Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache*, an ongoing academic project to map the occurrence of word variants to German-speaking areas, has a nice [entry](http://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/runde_2/f04/) for this.

[image: kehren fegen Sprachatlas]

<sub>Source: [Universität Augsburg - Philologisch-Historische Fakultät](http://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/runde_2/f04/)</sub>

Comment: The map/chart is very useful thanks.

Comment: danke @splattne :-) Ich habe noch nicht herausgefunden, wie man unter iOS Bilder bei GL&U einfügen kann...

Comment: @Jan :-) Ich glaube, dass ich das auch noch nie geschafft habe.

Comment: Heißt die Kehrmaschine, die morgens um halber 6 unbescholtene Bürger weckt, dann auch Fegemaschine im Norden? Und gibt es im Süden ein Kehrfeuer für die, die nicht umfegen? Kaminkehrer/Kaminfeger habe ich beides schon gehört. Der flotte Feger (:=Schuß, Möhre, Biene, Schnecke, ...), der eine Die ist, hat aber wiederum keine Entsprechung, soweit ich weiß.

Answer (score 6):

When regarding the etymology of both verbs there are interesting findings:

> **kehren** Vb. 'fegen'. Das nur westgerm. bezeugte Verb ahd. *kerien*, *kerren* (8. Jh.), mhd. *kern*, mnd. mnl. ***kēren***, nl. *keren* setzt germ. *karjan* voraus. Das zugehörige Grundwort dürfte in ahd. *ubarkara* 'Unreinigkeit, Unflat' (10./11. Jh.), isl. *kar* 'Schmutz' erhalten sein.<sup>[DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=kehren&hidx=1)</sup>

This means that despite its usage in the south *"kehren"* has a common root in *[Niederdeutsch](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niederdeutsche_Sprache)*.

> **fegen** Vb. 'mit dem Besen reinigen, kehren', südd. 'naß reinigen, wischen' ahd. *fegōn* 'säubern, putzen' (10. Jh.), mhd. *vegen* 'kehren, reinigen, putzen', asächs. *fegon*, mnd. *vēgen*, mnl. *vēghen*, nl. *vegen*, ablautend mnl. *vāghen*, nl. *(weg)vagen*, anord. *fāga* 'reinigen, glänzend machen, schmücken' sowie die unter ***fair*** (s. d.) genannten germ. Formen können mit lit. *puõšti* 'schmücken, putzen', lett. *post* 'schmücken' auf eine Wurzel ie. *pek̑-* 'hübsch machen, aufgeräumt oder vergnügt sein' zurückgeführt werden [...]<sup>[DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=fegen)</sup>

Taken this into account *"fegen"* may have much older [Indo-European](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_languages) roots, and is etymologically related to the English adjective *"fair"*.

Comment: what about the word "Kehre", a change of direction (http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kehre)?

Comment: *Kehre* und *kehren* sollen vom germanischen *kairjan* abstammen, haben also eine etymologisch **andere** Wurzel.

Answer (score 2):

Kehren has also another meaning - "to change direction". Wasser abkehren, Kehrbach, Kehre (Kurve)